# Запрос на поиск тектса в Mysql игнорируя HTML

Tags: html, mysql

Добрый день.

Проблема такого характера в базе хранится контент динамически генерируемых на сайте страниц. Хранится вместе с HTML тегами. Когда выполняется запрос в базу на поиск записей like по заданной строке mysql находит вхождения и в текст и в HTML теги. Есть ли возможность заставить Mysql игнорировать HTML?

Comment: Живой пример, почему плохо хранить html в базе, вместо данных

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13409726/5006740

Comment: нет.. нужно потом  полученный текст дополнительно обработать на php/js и тд

Comment: «хранится просто текст в БД» и «хранится вместе с HTML тегами» — фразы взаимоисключающие, определитесь пожалуйста

Comment: мне необходимо что бы во время выполнения запроса в базу, сервер игнорировал записи которые совпадают со строкой поиска в HTML теге. Мне нужно избежать повторного перебора записей в PHP

Comment: там по ссылке дальше ответ: или храни текст без тегов в другой колонке, или используй sphynx/lucene. cо встроем fulltext - никак

Answer (score 2):

В принципе такая возможность есть. Надо создать собственную функцию, которая удалит теги из текста:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags(str text) RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE start, end INT DEFAULT 1;
    IF str IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;
    LOOP
        SET start = LOCATE("<", str, start);
        IF (!start) THEN RETURN str; END IF;
        SET end = LOCATE(">", str, start);
        IF (!end) THEN SET end = start; END IF;
        SET str = INSERT(str, start, end - start + 1, "");
    END LOOP;
    RETURN str;
END;
//
```

После ее создания можем выполнять like по тексту без тегов:

```
select *
  from table
 where strip_tags(html_field) like '%text%'
```

Но, надо понимать, что выполнение самой функции над каждым значением из колонки занимает время. Плюс к этому никакие индексы для выполнения такого запроса использоваться не могут в принципе, что приведет к полному сканированию таблицы при каждом запросе. Поэтому если таблица большая настоятельно рекомендуется хранить готовый текст без тегов в отдельном поле и возможно использовать полнотекстовый поиск.